# Validate Parameters as a JSON String in Laravel

Tags: php, json, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-validation

**Front End Part**

The parameters are being sent like this:

[image: Front End sending data]

**Laravel Request**

```
class CarCreateRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        //TODO: Define authorization logic, possibly a middleware
        return true;
    }  

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'car.name' => 'present|required'
        ];
    }
}
```

**Real Problem**

The request class always validates to false. I checked the [Validating Array](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#validating-arrays) section, but it looks like this works sending parameters like this:

```
car[name]=Spidey Mobile
```

However, I need to send this data stringified using JSON.stringify().

Is there a workaround for this? It looks like dot notation isn't working since this is a JSON string rather than an array. I've tried modifying the request data before being evaluated, but I haven't found anything that works for Laravel 5.7.

Comment: how did you modify the request data before being evaluated? That would be your best bet. ```json_decode``` your request and set as the validation data.

Comment: `car: {"name": "Spidey Mobile"}` does not seem like a valid json format. `{"car": {"name": "Spidey Mobile"}}` is.

Comment: Just as a side note, you don't need `present` and `required` in your validation as `required` alone will check that the field is present, as well as it not being empty.

Comment: @CUGreen I used json_decode within the ValidationData method but it looks like it's no longer available for 5.7. It's not changing anything at all

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's the solution, I used both the sanitize and validator method within the request in order to change the request data before being evaluated.

```
class CarCreateRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
    * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
    *
    * @return bool
    */
    public function authorize()
    {
        //TODO: Define authorization logic, possibly a middleware
        return true;
    }  

    public function validator($factory)
    {
    return $factory->make(
        $this->sanitize(), $this->container->call([$this, 'rules']), $this->messages()
    );
    }

    public function sanitize()
    {
        $this->merge([
            'car' => json_decode($this->input('car'), true)
        ]);
        return $this->all();
    }

    /**
    * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
    *
    * @return array
    */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'car.name' => 'present|required'
        ];
    }
}
```

The json_decode will transform the JSON string into an array that can be validated by Laravel.

Answer (score 5):

You should just be able to override the [validationData](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/6f278c4a2623dd43524cefe734161b191fff1764/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/FormRequest.php#L111) method in your Request like this:

```
protected function validationData()
{
    $this->merge(['car', json_decode($this->car)]); // or what ever your request value is.
    return $this->all();
}
```

Comment: I'm sure that this method is there for a reason? Are you sure you are Casting your request to ```CarCreateRequest``` in your controllers store method? Try and ```dd($this->all());``` in ```validationData()``` to make sure it is passing through and returning the correct data.